# If $f_n\le f$ is almost everywhere on a set, then is $|f_n|\le |f|$ also?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f_n\le f$ is almost everywhere on a set,
then is $|f_n|\le |f|$ ıs also almost everywhere on the same set.

where $\lbrace f_n \rbrace$ are non-negative
Could you please explain

Comment: It's not true even pointwisely. Think of $-2<1$.

Comment: sorry. i forgot to add that $f_n$s are non-negative. editted as such.

Comment: If $f_n$ is nonnegative, then so is $f$ and $|f_n| = f_n \le f = |f|$.

Answer (score 2):

since $\lbrace f_n \rbrace$ are non-negative so $|f_n|=f_n$. then $|f_n|=f_n \le f = |f| $